# The column name "FirstName" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting the following error message when I am trying to do replace `null` to `zero`.

> The column name "jan" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with
>   the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.

Query below:

```
select * from(select isnull(jan,0),isnull(feb,0),sum(data) as amount )as p
pivot(
sum(amount) for month in(jan,feb)) as piv
```

Comment: Can you put sample data + expected results?

Comment: @ManoJohnbritto - please *[edit]* your question to add sample data and expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CTE` to define your null values and then pivot the data something like this:

```
;WITH t
AS (
    SELECT isnull(jan, 0) AS jan
        ,isnull(feb, 0) AS feb
        ,sum(data) AS amount
    FROM your_table --change this to match your table name
    GROUP BY jan,feb
    )
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t.jan
        ,t.feb
        ,t.amount
    FROM t
    )
pivot(sum(amount) FOR [month] IN (
            jan
            ,feb
            )) AS piv
```

Comment: Thanku Nepali,Why using with

Comment: `WITH` clause helps you build a query and do all your null logic(in your case), which then can be used in your second part of the query without having to do any type of data manipulation. If you are interested, here is more information on using `CTE` in sql server. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/

Answer (score 3):

It's like the error says your column names are wrong because they will be read as un-named. Give them their appropriate names:

```
select isnull(Jan,0), isnull(feb,0) from(select sum(data) as amount, [month] 
from yourtable group by [month] )as p
pivot(
sum(amount) for [month] in(jan,feb)) as piv
```

Comment: I think the use of "month" is causing chaos as that is a reserved word. Is it a column in your table?

Comment: You need to select "month" in the first select too or whatever you have renamed month to.

Comment: You have any idea replace null to zero on this query

Comment: I've updated my code to what should work but this assumes [month] will contain "jan" or "feb" if this is not what you want you'll need to update your question with what your expected results are.

Comment: Thanku so much Barron,